# How do i change my display name in Linux without adminstrator privileges?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, administrator, root

I recently got an account in a network, and the administrator misspelled my name. Is there a way to change it on my own?

Comment: Any reason you can't simply as the administrator to change it for you?

Comment: You should definitely ask the administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Accounts can be modified by the `usermod` command (for example for changing your username you'll run `usermod -l new_name current_name`) which can be run only by superuser.

Also, you shouldn't be logged in when changing your username. Actually, you probably even *can't* be logged in, since `usermod` will fail if any process is run under your username.



EDIT: I didn't notice your title and automatically thought of changing *username*, not *display name*. I will leave that part here since it might help someone.

You can change your display name using `usermod -c` while being logged in, but you still need to have root access in order to run `usermod`.

However, display names can be changed also by `chfn -f new_name`. The command itself doesn't need privileged user, *but it might fail* depending on **/etc/login.defs** configuration for `CHFN_RESTRICT` (and in order to change the file, you also need superuser access).

Comment: Yes, i suspected that, but i wanted to be sure. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sorry, while this is a good answer, it's still got more wrong than right. `usermod` has nothing to do with domain accounts, it is limited to /etc/passwd only (one would use LDAP to edit LDAP accounts, for example), and it works fine when you're logged in (unless you're trying to change your username or UID – but the original question is not about the username, it specifically says _display name_).

Comment: @grawity Thank you for pointing things out - I assumed only /etc/passwd entries, of course using any other identity provider would need a specific command (but I didn't see any mention of that in the post). On the other hand, I am completely blind and by reading 'name' I automatically thought of username, not display name - now I see it's even in the title! Will adjust answer to that.

Comment: Well usually "account on the network" sorta implies LDAP / AD / NIS. Though I misread the question as saying "domain account", which would imply that more strongly.

Answer (score 1):

No, and also proactive actions may not be appreciated by the IT guy (maybe there's dependent apps or documentation to be filled) so I'd  encourage you to ask them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

usermod -l newname oldname

Comment: Doesn't work - requires root (su) access.